# Jquery - Getting all the contents of a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am pretty new to jquery, or any web technology for that matter.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form id = "featureform">
        <!-- Table inside the form -->
        <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped">
            <!-- First Row -->
            <tr id = "tableRow1">
                <td><input id="from_checkbox" class="form-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked
                                            data-toggle="toggle" data-on="From" data-off="From"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="from_text" value="tester@test.com"></td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Second Row -->
            <tr id = "tableRow2">
                <td><input id="to_checkbox" class="form-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked
                                            data-toggle="toggle" data-on="To" data-off="To"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="to_text" value="myself@dummy.com"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

So I have a table inside a form. Each row of the table has 2 columns.The first column will contain a [bootstrap toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) checkbox. The text field will hold the value for that specific checkbox. Both input types (checkbox, and text field) have ids associated with them.

Here is what I want to do:

**Help needed here**: When the user toggles the checkbox, I want to know the "id" of the checkbox and the textfield.

This table will have multiple rows, so hardcoding for every row based on the ID is not the solution. I am looking for a generic solution that looks like this:

```
//form-input-checkbox is the class name assigned for every checkbox. So we monitor any events coming from these
//   checkboxes, and do the magic
$(".form-input-checkbox").change(function(){
    // Extract the id of the checkbox
    // Extract the id of the textfield in this row
    console.log($(this).closest("tr"));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `attr()` method to get the id property value. To get a reference to the text field, First use `closest()` method to get a reference to the outer tr and use `find()` method to get the input field.

This should work.

```
$(".form-input-checkbox").change(function(){
    var _this=$(this);

    alert(_this.attr("id"));
    alert(_this.closest("tr").find("input[type='text']").attr("id"));
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/sosibaqeme/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

Comment: Thank you. This is working. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input:checkbox[data-toggle='toggle']").change(function() {
            var $checkbox = $(this);

            var checkboxId = $checkbox.attr("id");
            var inputId = $checkbox.parent().next("td").find("input:text").attr("id");

            console.log(checkboxId);
            console.log(inputId);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

your code should be like this:

```
$(".form-input-checkbox").change(function(){
   // Extract the id of the checkbox
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        // Extract the id of the textfield in this row
    console.log($(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='text']").attr("id"));

});
```

this a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/43gZUqVuluwi1C7bzYeb?p=preview)